# WSO2 DSS - No operations allowed after connection closed in EI 6.1.1

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am facing Exception like **"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed"** in WSO2 DSS often by using WSO2 Ei 6.1.1.

**Exception**:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:axis2ns1244="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
  <soapenv:Code>
     <soapenv:Value>axis2ns1244:DATABASE_ERROR</soapenv:Value>
  </soapenv:Code>
  <soapenv:Reason>
     <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR Nested Exception:- javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: Error in 'createProcessedPreparedStatement' DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR Nested Exception:- com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.  DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR Source Data Service:- Name: AR_DropDown_NAC_Merge Location: /AR_DropDown_NAC_Merge.dbs Description: N/A Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice Current Request Name: AR_Salesperson_DropDown_appRevenue_Oper Current Params: {Salesperson_Query=25} Nested Exception:- DS Fault Message: Error in 'createProcessedPreparedStatement' DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR Nested Exception:- com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.   </soapenv:Text>
  </soapenv:Reason>
  <soapenv:Detail>
```

**DSS Config:**

```
<config enableOData="false" id="DropDown_NAC_Merge_Datasource">
      <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://host_name:3306/db_name</property>
      <property name="username">user_name</property>
      <property name="password">password</property>
      <property name="maxActive">55</property>
      <property name="minIdle">1</property>
   </config>
```

I tried to change maxActive=55, and minIdle=1. when enable these configuration level changes in DSS, it's works fine. but after some time (either one day or 2 days) again facing the same issue. can i get any permanent solution for this?

**Note**: the mysql database max_connections has barely reached its limit ( 5 connections used out of 150 )

Answer (score 0):

I think MySQL is implicitly closing the database connection after some inactive time.
The first thing I would try would be adding **?autoReconnect=true** to connection url, like this:

```
<property name="url">jdbc:mysql://host_name:3306/db_name?autoReconnect=true</property>
```

Comment: Hi @tmoasz,
Thanks for your suggestion, I have implemented the same, let see what'll happen in the upcoming days. will let u know the status

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any batch operations. Then the issues can be due to https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2403